# Powershell code errors when executed using 'Run with PowerShell' but runs OK in PS Editor

Tags: powershell

Work continues on migrating my HTA to an XAML-based, PowerShell-driven form...

When I run my script inside PSE, the hiding/unhiding of grids using the 'Visibility' property, driven from the user selecting a drop-down item, works great. However, if I run it using Explorer's 'Run with PowerShell' context menu, or from a PS command prompt, I get the error "The property 'Visibility' cannot be found on this object" when the drop-down selection changes.

For completeness, here's the function which is in an imported .PSM1 file:

```
Function cmbDeploymentPurpose_OnSelectionChanged($Form, $SelectedValue){
    If ($SelectedValue.ToString() -eq "System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem: Available") 
    {
        $grdDeploymentSettings_Available.Visibility = "Visible"
        $grdDeploymentSettings_Required.Visibility = "Hidden"
        $grdScheduling_Required.Visibility = "Hidden"
    }
    ElseIf ($SelectedValue.ToString() -eq "System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem: Required") 
    {
        $grdDeploymentSettings_Available.Visibility = "Hidden"
        $grdDeploymentSettings_Required.Visibility = "Visible"
        $grdScheduling_Required.Visibility = "Visible"
    }
}
```

and here's the relevant event creation:

```
$cmbDeploymentPurpose.Add_SelectionChanged({cmbDeploymentPurpose_OnSelectionChanged $Form $cmbDeploymentPurpose.SelectedValue}.GetNewClosure())
```

In each case, the user credentials are the same.

Comment: Sounds like a scoping issue, try using the variable expression `$script:grdDeploymentSettings_Available` instead of `$grdDeploymentSettings_Available` (whether it works depends which scope the variables where created in though)

Comment: Thanks for that but having added that and tried 'global:' instead of 'script;' it still errors.